# What does the "thickness" measurement in a t molding measurement actually describe?

Tags: flooring, trim

I'm trying to buy t-molding online for hardwood that is 1/2" from subfloor to top of the hardwood, so I would like a t-molding that is 1/2" from the bottom to where the t-molding would rest on the hardwood.  But I can't tell if the descriptions measure from the bottom to where the t-molding rests on the hardwood, or if it measures the thickest part of the trim piece.

For example, in this [HD product description](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Mohawk-Vintage-Oak-9-16-in-Thick-x-2-in-Wide-x-84-in-Length-Hardwood-T-Molding-HTMDA-05537/206922981):

"9/16 in. Thick x 2 in. Wide x 84 in. Length"

Is it 9/16" from the bottom to the where it would touch the floor?  Or 9/16" from the bottom to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is going to be 9/16" total thickness.  From the top to the bottom.  Only a more detailed drawing is going to tell the exact height and width of the tongue portion.

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like I won't be able to use these general measurements to buy online.  I either need to find a listing with more detailed measurements, or measure & buy in-store.

Comment: Mohawk is a HUGE flooring company.  I wouldn't be surprised to find very detailed information on their website.  It would be worth checking out.